# how to properly shrink wrap a torus looking thing

Tags: bezier-curves, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to shrink wrap "cloth" to a torus looking object. It was going fine until I reach the quarter of the torus, the shrink wrap isn't working as I expected.

Here's the image of my current model

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

The wrap is overlapping on itself right now, but it's currently my biggest concern. As you can see from the images, the wrap twisted on the quarter way and rotating the curve vertices doesn't really fix it. What configuration of the shrink wrap should I use? Because I think this could be a shrink wrap issue. I'll upload my blend file so you guys can check it out.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the *Shrink Wrap* modifier but the curve guide that you've created that causes the problems.

Curves have normals and can be tilted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in *Edit* mode. In *Edit* mode, you also can activate the *[X] Normals* overlay. Just lower the number for the length to `0.005` else you will get a mess with the default value:
[image: normals of the curve guide]
<sup>Normals of the curve guide</sup>

Now you can see the problem. The curve guide is twisted. You get a better result if you tilt them so they follow the torus:

[image: fixed normals]
<sup>Fixed normals</sup>

Select a control point in *Edit* mode and tilt it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> & *move mouse*)

[image: tilt animation]

Then the *Shrink Wrap* modifier can do a better job. Final result:

[image: final result]

(Please note, I was confused by your settings ;-) So I've changed a few things as seen in the screenshots:

- rotated the "cloth" (*handle wrap 2*) and aligned it along the Y-axis. (Yours is aligned along the X-axis and is laid out "flat".)
- changed the *Array* modifier from *[_] Constant Offset* to *[X] Relative Offset*, and set *Factor Y* to `1.000`
- set the *Curve* modifier's *Deform Axis* from `-X` to `Y`)

[image: cloth mesh]

Comment: wow, I didn't know a lot of things was affecting that. Honestly, I was just "brute forcing" that model with what I know. Will try your answer