# How do I wrap a wire around a torus into a X shape like in the image without the wire deforming

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: example]

I'm trying create something like the x shaped wire on the bottom of the torus. I tried using the skinwrap modifier and manually creating it by snaping the vertices to the torus but it ends up deformed

Comment: Try to cut it on the tourus with the "Bisect" tool and extrude it.

Comment: it started to deform the mesh after 2 cuts

Comment: do you use a curve? Here is a similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/235744/107598